# How can I use inline variables in a .bat file?

Tags: shell, batch-file, command-line, command

I need to convert the following to be compatible with a batch script.

```
cmd.exe cd " + homepath + "\\" + a
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=file://"+ homepath + "/.m2/repository
1
c
b
c
uuid.toString()
Y
cd " + homepath +"\\"+ a +"\\" + b
vn clean install
"cd " + homepath +"\\" + a
a
cd " + homepath +"\\" + a +"\\" + b + "\\" + b + "-plugin" + "\\target
jar -xvf " + zipDirectory
cmd cd " + homepath +"\\" + a +"\\" + b + "\\" + b + "-plugin" + "\\target\\" + "\\META-INF\\maven\\" + c + "\\" + b + "-plugin
copy pom.xml " + pluginDirectory
cd " + pluginDirectory
rename pom.xml " + b + "-plugin-1.0.0.pom
color 0a
```

For a line like the first one:

```
cmd.exe cd " + homepath + "\\" + a
```

Would the line look like this?

```
SET homepath = C:\Users\Joe\
SET a = plugins
cmd.exe cd echo %homepath% echo %a%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in batch, there is no string concatenation symbol like on (other) programming languages. You just use the variable instead of the string:

```
set homepath=%userprofile%
set a=plugins
echo homepath is %homepath% and a is %a%.
cd %homepath%\%a%
```

(Note: do not use spaces around `=` with the `set` command - they would be part of the variable name respectively the value)

Comment: How can I confirm that my script has executed? When running the bat file it just flickers on then off instantaneously.

Comment: Nevermind. To test I wrote this: `mkdir batchscript`

Comment: don*t run batchfiles per doubleclick while still testing/debugging. Run it directly from command prompt to see any errormessages. Also there is the `pause` command, which waits for a keypress.

Comment: Oh okay got it. That's a lot better.